# "shrink-wrapping" floated elements doesn't work quite as well as expected

Tags: html, css

I want an element that grows in *width* with its children, the children are floated left, I want the parent to be centered inside its parent. When the floated children begin to wrap, the width is ~20px bigger on one side, I don't want that.

In theory I have what I want with this:

**HTML**

```
<div id="postImg"> 
    <span id="centerFloats">
        <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
        <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
        <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
         <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
        <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
        <div class="boxCon">
        </div>
    </span>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
body{
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
div#postImg {
    float:left;
    width:100%;
    position:relative;
    text-align:center;
    background-color:green;
}
#centerFloats {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:left;
    background-color:red;
}
div.boxCon {
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    background-color:#fff;
    border:3px solid #ddd;
    margin-top:10px;
}
```

**Fiddle**
http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/qLbvg/

**My problem is that the parent isn't tight enough around the children, so when the floated boxes start to drop to the next line, there's a ~20px gap on the right hand side.**

What is causing this gap and how do I get the parent element to shrink tighter around the children?

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "shrink wrap effect".

Comment: You get a gap ... is the expected behavior if the space isnt enogh then the box go to the next line. This is another option http://jsfiddle.net/qLbvg/5/

Comment: @Danko I've re worded my question. Your example isn't what I want as I don't like the look of that one box on it's own in the middle, I have looked at that option too.

Comment: Using fixed pixel widths within percentage widths is usually a pain. Do the inner elements have to be 100px wide?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, hmmm, you have a point I guess. But then when more content is added they wont float and start new lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to this problem was to make the parent element `text-align:justify;` and the children `display:inline-block;`.

**CSS**

```
body{
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
    }
    div#postImg {
        float:left;
        width:100%;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        background-color:green;
    }
    #centerFloats {
        display:inline-block;
        text-align:justify;
        background-color:red;
    }
    div.boxCon {
        width:100px;
        height:100px;
        display:inline-block;
        position:relative;
        background-color:#fff;
        border:3px solid #ddd;
        margin-top:10px;
    }
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="postImg"> 
        <span id="centerFloats">
            <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
            <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
            <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
             <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
            <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
            <div class="boxCon">
            </div>
        </span>
    </div>
```

**Fiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/SEOplay/qLbvg/9/

Answer (score 0):

I think you skipped over Danko's reasoning though... The gap is due to the fact that the block elements move down to the lower row when the width is too small for them to fit next to each other. If each box is `50px` wide and you have no padding they will fit cleanly, 6 across, on a `300px` space.

If that space is reduced to `299px`, the 6th box no longer fits, so it floats down to the next row and the space you see is the remaining 5 boxes "floating left" and the `49px` gap is natural.

I could set up a fiddle, but we've seen 2 that show both available options. I'm not exactly sure how else to answer this...

Comment: Okay, I understand that now, give me another option, even with jQuery, where the parent element is always shrunk tight around the floated children. So even when the floated children begin to wrap there won't be that 20px gap on the right hand side. This is what I'm asking.

Comment: Text-align:justify; was what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

If the child elements must have fixed widths and you want the centered parent wrapper to 'shrink' with the inner elements there really is no good way to make this work. [Flexbox](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) would most likely be the best solution, but it's not currently in all browsers.

A hack to get this working is to use media queries. For example:

```
@media (max-width: 600px){
    #centerFloats { width:500px; }
}
```

For a full example see: http://jsfiddle.net/hG5KT/

**Note:** Using a `div` inside a `span` tag is invalid HTML as you're using a block-level element inside an inline-element. Just use a `div` tag instead of a `span` for `#centerFloats`.